# Retrieve Object Position for Projection Shadow Calculation

Tags: c++, opengl

I am working on a class project and I need to implement shadows into our project, using OpenGL-esque coding. Our specific project is a spider running around a house. I need to make shadows appear on the floor below the spider (don't care about shadows for anything else).

The main question I need answered is this: When calculating shadows, **How do I retrieve a point on the spider?** In our notes, it says we have 3 givens in order to begin our initial calculations: 1) Plane (we know A,B,C,D)   2) Light source at (Lx,Ly,Lz)   3) Point q in space: Shadow caster

I do not understand how to retrieve "q". We load the spider mesh using "Mesh" and "SuperMesh" classes, and pass the mesh onto the vertex shader, but I do not understand how to reference points on the spider while on the CPU side.

I'm hesitant to post all of my code, mainly because this project uses a special library "llgl" that's based on OpenGL that our teacher made explicity for this class (makes debugging super easy, right?), and I'm not entirely sure what all would be needed in order to have my question properly answered. I'll include the Mesh and SuperMesh classes, as well as the declarations of loading the spider and passing it to the vertex shader as a matrix (which is more relevant). If you need more code, please request it. Hopefully it's more of a "theory" response than a syntax response, so I don't frustrate anyone trying to understand our code, haha.

Thank you for your time.

**Main:** (literally all of the excess code is cut out for simplicity)

```
...
SuperMesh* spider = new SuperMesh("spider/SmoothSpider.spec.mesh");
mat4 spiderR = rotationY(M_PI);      // Rotation matrix for spider
vec3 spiderT(0,-2.5,-8.0);  // Translation for spider
...

... (in draw)
//prog1 simply defines the txt files for the vertex and fragment shader
prog1->setUniform("worldMatrix",  // sets world matrix for spider
        spiderR * translation(vec4(spiderT.x,
                                    spiderT.y,
                                    spiderT.z,
                                    0.0)));
    spider->draw(prog1);
...
```

**Mesh:** (Hopefully not needed)

```
#ifndef MESH_H
#define MESH_H

#include "llgl.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace llgl;

class Mesh{
  public:
    string fname;
    bool initialized;
    vector<uint8_t> vdata;
    vector<uint8_t> idata;
    vec4 color;
    vec4 scolor;
    int isize;
    GLenum ienum;
    unsigned vbuff,ibuff;
    uint32_t ni;
    TextureX* diffusetex;
    TextureX* ramp;//used for cell shading, this is the "gradient"

    Mesh(string fname);
    void setup();
    void draw(Program& prog);
    void draw(Program* prog){ draw(*prog); }

};


#endif
```

**SuperMesh:**

```
#pragma once

#include "Mesh.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct SuperMesh
{
    vector<Mesh*> m;
    string fname;
    bool loaded;
    SuperMesh(string specfile)
    {
        fname = specfile;
        loaded = false;
    }

    void load()
    {
        if(loaded)
            return;

        ifstream in(fname.c_str());
        if(!in.good())
            throw runtime_error("Cannot load file " + fname);

        string pfx;
        unsigned slashidx;
        slashidx = fname.find("/");
        if(slashidx == string::npos)
            slashidx = fname.find("\\");
        if(slashidx != string::npos)
            pfx = fname.substr(0, slashidx) + "/";

        while(1)
        {
            string s;
            getline(in, s);
            if(in.fail())
                break;

            if(s.find("binarymesh ") == 0)
            {
                string fname = s.substr(11);
                m.push_back(new Mesh(pfx + fname));
                m.back()->setup();
            }
        }
        loaded = true;
    }

    void draw(Program* p)
    {
        if(!loaded)
            load();
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < m.size(); ++i)
        {
            m[i]->draw(p);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You don't retrieve points on the mesh for shadowing. All you need to do is project them from the perspective of the light (which is what vertex shaders are for), whether you are using shadow volumes or shadow maps this is the basic underlying principle.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Hmm, okay. That leads me to another question, because in our notes, we are given ludicrious amounts of math for the matrix equation, which constantly references q. Am I misunderstanding what q is supposed to represent? Here's a small example of the notes we were given:

Comment: Where does ray strike plane?
Where plane equation satisfied
Substitute for x,y,z in plane equation:
A( tqx) + B(tqy) + C(tqz) + D = 0
Solve for the one unknown (t)
t = -D / (A qx + B qy + C qz )